# How to print citations in a beamer presentation with the same style used for articles

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
\begin{filecontents}{lib.bib}
@book{stallings2016wireless,
  title={Wireless Communication Networks and Systems},
  author={Stallings, W. and Beard, C.},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Pearson}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is an example \cite{stallings2016wireless}.
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{lib}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]

Now, I want to print citation like an article style (as shown in the figure below) in my beamer file.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the color and font family of the bibliography using various templates as described in the [beamer manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) on page 104. In this case you need to set the properties for the `bibliography item` and repeat those for the `bibliography entry author`, because the author field uses a separate set of properties but subsequent fields like `bibliography entry title` use the currently active color and font family. MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\rmfamily\insertbiblabel}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography item}{fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry author}{\rmfamily} % roman font instead of sans serif
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=black}
\begin{filecontents}{lib.bib}
@book{stallings2016wireless,
  title={Wireless Communication Networks and Systems},
  author={Stallings, W. and Beard, C.},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Pearson}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is an example \cite{stallings2016wireless}.
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{lib}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, as you see the publisher and year are printed at the next line. How I can put them on the previous line?

Comment: @ADiyanat I think that is part of the IEEE bibliography style, your example screenshot from the article also has the publisher and year on the next line. So if you want to change this you would need to change the bibliography style file, or renew `\newblock`, but that would probably be better asked in a separate question.